# Multiple repositories for same data store but different domain logic?

Tags: domain-driven-design, software-design, event-driven-design

I am building a feature that is powered by a given table, called `Urls`, structured as below:

`externalId| activatedId | url | userId`

This table is populated, driven by 2 scenarios (flows):

1. Whenever a user creates an account in my system, a event is then consumed from a kafka queue to retrieve the **user id** and **url**. These are then persisted `Urls` on the corresponding columns.
   So at this point we do have `externalId` and `activatedId` nulled .
2. `externalId` and `activatedId` are populated at a later stage, after a user do activate its account. This will mean that `userId` will also be nulled from table, keeping `url` untouched.

Given these are two independent flows, and am trying to design both flows in a **domain driven approach**, i am considering to create 2 repositories, accessig the same `Urls` table:

1. `UserCreateRepository`
2. `UserActivationRepository`

Each repository would then have knowledge of it's own representation of the Url:

1. `UserCreateRepository` would use`UserCreationUrl`;
2. `UserActivationRepository` would use `UserActivationUrl`;

I would like to open a discussion to understand **what is the best approach**, as i feel that having only one repository will mix boths flows and we're handling different scenario entities.

Comment: Maybe one of the solutions would be to have 2 different tables that would represent those 2 entities, but they are also related, so am a bit divided here

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follow Domain Driven Design approach, you should start modeling the domain at first. The infrastructure part (database, repository) comes later, as it should adjust to already modeled domain.
Based on your problem, you should find out what is the aggregate root here. 
Based on DDD principles you should have only one repository for one aggregate root.
Now it's your turn to identify the aggregate. 
I am thinking that your flow described above consists of two steps:

- User creates an account: userId and Url for activation is being
  generated
- Account must be activated

So, my suggestion is something like this (pseudocode):

```
class User : AggregateRoot
{
   SetupAccount(userId, url) {...}
   Activate() {...}
}
```

It looks like having one aggregate here, only one repository is suitable...